# where & how to use onKey,onkeyDown,onKeyPressed event in android?

Tags: android

hi
  where to use onKey and onKeyUp/Down event in android.

e.g. i have one textview . when user pressed any key i want to display that character in textview,
     In this case which event(above) is used.

```
PLEASE explain with EXAMPLE
```

Or give some other example that get the key event and print in edittext or some other.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: To gain reputation, and make others to answer your question, accepts the good answers of your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pls refer the following code

```
public class Demo extends Activity
 {

    /**
     *  Variables & Objects Declaration
     * 
     */


     EditText  et;

     private static Context CONTEXT;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        et =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.header_text02);
        }// end of OnCreate

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(View arg0, Editable arg1, int arg2, KeyEvent arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("I am ","KeyDown");
           switch (keyCode) {
                   case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
                   {
                       //your Action code
                       et.setText("A");
                      return true;
                    }
                      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B:
                   {
                       //your Action code
                       et.setText("B");
                      return true;
                    }
                   // similarly write for others too
        }



        return true;
    }// End of onKeyDown



    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(View arg0, Editable arg1, int arg2, KeyEvent arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("I am ","KeyUp");
            et.setText("KeyUp");
        return true;
    }// End of onKeyUp



}
```

Comment: @shankar can u help me to show alert message on home button press.

Answer (score 12):

If you are looking this in EditText, its better to use these

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
                    Log.v("TAG", "afterTextChanged");
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    Log.v("TAG", "beforeTextChanged");
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    Log.v("TAG", "onTextChanged");
                }
            });
```