# hook power key and detect volume key is press when screen is turn off

Tags: android

As the title, I have two problems:
1. Hook power key- I need detect and prevent power key.
2. When screen is off, i need to handle event foe volume,menu,back key press.

Comment: hello, you should provide sample of your code. Did you try to use search engine on SO ?

Comment: I have been seaching for it. But I have no answer for my problems. Maybe you don't understand all off my question, else please give me the link.

Answer (score -1):

[KeyEvents stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171949/where-how-to-use-onkey-onkeydown-onkeypressed-event-in-android) This link lets you know how to handle onKeyUp/Down event.

For Back key detection use KEYCODE_BACK

For Volume Keys use KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN and KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP

[list of Key events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

[Detecting menu button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239880/detecting-physical-menu-key-press-in-android)

OnStop() lifecycle method of a activity is called when power button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.but it not work if screen is turn off.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I'have made the edit .Refer to Activity life cycle . http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html .Hope it helps